# How to get an image resource from within an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resources

I've made a `UserControl`.
This `UserControl` contains two files:
MyControl.xaml and MyControl.xaml.cs.
In the XAML file there are some `DrawingImage` resources:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
         ...
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <DrawingImage x:Key="circleActive">
              <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                   <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V24 H24 V0 H0 Z">
                        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFFF0000"
                                     Geometry="F1 M24,24z M0,0z M12,0C8.699219,0,6,2.699219,6,6L6,11 3,11 3,24 21,24 21,11 18,11 18,6C18,2.699219,15.300781,0,12,0z M12,2C14.21875,2,16,3.78125,16,6L16,11 8,11 8,6C8,3.78125,9.78125,2,12,2z" />
                   </DrawingGroup>
              </DrawingImage.Drawing>
         </DrawingImage>
         ...
```

Now I have an `IValueConverter` in the MyControls.xaml.cs file.

I want to convert from integer values to the different image sources.
The only way I found is `Application.LoadComponent(...)`:

```
public class ObjectStateToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly ResourceDictionary ImageResources;

    static ObjectStateToImageConverter()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("/Bfe.Controls;component/Resources/ImageDictionary.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        ImageResources = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(uri);
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int intValue)
        {
            switch (intValue)
            {
                case 0: return ImageResources["circleInactive"];
                case 1: return ImageResources["circleActive"];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I can't believe, that this is the right way.
Why must I load something, that should be already there?
Other Elements in the `UserControl` can show the `DrawingImage`s static in the XAML.

Is there another way to get the `DrawingImage` resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=net-5.0) in order to bind bind the object state and the current control. Then you can leverage the [`FindResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findresource?view=net-5.0) method defined on `FrameworkElement` to get a resource.

```
public class ObjectStateToImageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values == null || values.Length != 2 || !(values[0] is int intValue) || !(values[1] is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
         return null;

      switch (intValue)
      {
         case 0: return frameworkElement.FindResource("circleInactive");
         case 1: return frameworkElement.FindResource("circleActive");
         default: return null;
      }
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

In XAML use a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=net-5.0) to bind your object state (adapt it if necessary) and the control itself.

```
<Image>
   <Image.Source>
      <MultiBinding>
         <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <local:ObjectStateToImageConverter/>
         </MultiBinding.Converter>
         <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding/>
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
         </MultiBinding.Bindings>
      </MultiBinding>
   </Image.Source>
</Image>
```